# Flatten Nested JSON in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm quite stuck (I've gone through multiple other stackoverflows and other sites and still can't get this to work).

I've the below json coming out of an API connection

```
    {
   "results":[
      {
         "group":{
            "mediaType":"chat",
            "queueId":"67d9fb5e-26b2-4db5-b062-bbcfa8d2ca0d"
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "interval":"2021-01-14T13:12:19.000Z/2022-01-14T13:12:19.000Z",
               "metrics":[
                  {
                     "metric":"nOffered",
                     "qualifier":null,
                     "stats":{
                        "max":null,
                        "min":null,
                        "count":14,
                        "count_negative":null,
                        "count_positive":null,
                        "sum":null,
                        "current":null,
                        "ratio":null,
                        "numerator":null,
                        "denominator":null,
                        "target":null
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "views":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and what I'm mainly looking to get out of it is (or at least something as close as)

| MediaType | QueueId | NOffered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chat | 67d9fb5e-26b2-4db5-b062-bbcfa8d2ca0d | 14 |

Is something like that possible? I've tried multiple things and I either get the whole of this out in one line or just get different errors.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what error you got!

Comment: Tried 

a_json = json.loads(data_query_result)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_json, orient="index")
df = pd.json_normalize(dataframe)
print (df)

which just gives me an empty data frame. If I try to pass data_query_result right in to the json_normalize I get an error saying # check to see if a simple recursive function is possible to

NotImplementedError: 

Other attempts I've gotten String Indices must be integers error

Comment: Tried this too just earlier today 

https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got indicates you missed that some of your values are actually a dictionary within an array.

Assuming you want to *flatten* your json file to retrieve the following keys: `mediaType`, `queueId`, `count`.

These can be retrieved by the following sample code:

```
import json
with open(path_to_json_file, 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)

for result in json_dict.get("results"):
    media_type = result.get("group").get("mediaType")
    queue_id = result.get("group").get("queueId")
    n_offered = result.get("data")[0].get("metrics")[0].get("count")
```

If your `data` and `metrics` keys will have multiple indices you will have to use a `for` loop to retrieve every `count` value accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me. Had to change it to 

s = json_dict
d = json.loads(s)

for results in d.get("results"): 
    media_type = results.get("group").get("mediaType")
    queue_id = results.get("group").get("queueId")
    n_offered = results.get("data")[0].get("metrics")[0].get("stats").get("count")

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format of the API response is always the same, have you considered hardcoding the extraction of the data you want?

This should work: With `response` defined as the API output:

```
response =     {
   "results":[
      {
          "group":{
            "mediaType":"chat",
            "queueId":"67d9fb5e-26b2-4db5-b062-bbcfa8d2ca0d"
          },
          "data":[
            {
               "interval":"2021-01-14T13:12:19.000Z/2022-01-14T13:12:19.000Z",
               "metrics":[
                  {
                     "metric":"nOffered",
                     "qualifier":'null',
                     "stats":{
                        "max":'null',
                        "min":'null',
                        "count":14,
                        "count_negative":'null',
                        "count_positive":'null',
                        "sum":'null',
                        "current":'null',
                        "ratio":'null',
                        "numerator":'null',
                        "denominator":'null',
                        "target":'null'
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "views":'null'
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You can extract the results as follows:

```
results = response["results"][0]

{
    "mediaType": results["group"]["mediaType"],
    "queueId": results["group"]["queueId"],
    "nOffered": results["data"][0]["metrics"][0]["stats"]["count"]
}
```

which gives

```
{
    'mediaType': 'chat',
    'queueId': '67d9fb5e-26b2-4db5-b062-bbcfa8d2ca0d',
    'nOffered': 14
}
```

Comment: That worked when I tested it, but not scalable for what I'm trying to do so went with the other solution. Thanks